# how to pass table name as a parameter in UD scaller function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, error-handling

```
create function test
(
  @tblName as  sysname,
  @category as varchar(50)
)
returns int
as
begin 
  declare @val2 as int
  select @val2=val1 from @tblName where val1=@tblName 
  return @val2
end
```

Whats wrong with this query, it's throwing the following error

> Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Procedure test, Line 11
>   Must declare the table variable "@tblName".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't parameterise the table name. You would need to use dynamic SQL (not that this is allowed in functions anyway).

You might be able to use a View or CTE that `UNION ALL`s a fixed list of tables and a constant to do whatever you are trying to do. The code you have posted makes little sense 
(You want `@val2` to have the same value as `@tblName` if a table called the value of `@tblName` contains this same value in the `val1` column?!) but something like

```
;WITH cte AS
(
SELECT 'table1' AS table_name, val1
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'table2' AS table_name, val1
FROM table2
)
select @val2=val1 from cte where table_name=@tblName and val1 = @tblName
```

Comment: But i want to make generalize function to pase table name as parameter, the above query suggest me to make a hard coded value function. My requirement is quite different, function should be called for any table name as a paramter

Comment: @Novice - That would require dynamic SQL which isn't possible in a function so you can't. This type of technique is never a good idea in SQL Server anyway and probably indicates a bad design. Why don't you know in advance the tables you want to query? Are you sure these tables that all have a `val1` column should be separate at all?

Comment: you are true, but i was a=making it for my own learning...well thanks, but dont you think that there can arise any condition where i may ave to need like this?

Answer (score 1):

@tblName1 is decalred as @tblName in the function parameter